# Connection and Disconnection (AtCoder Grand Contest 039_A)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this task. [Source](https://atcoder.jp/contests/agc039/tasks/agc039_a)

A string S is given. Let T be the concatenation of K copies of S. We can repeatedly perform the following operation: Choose a character in T and replace it with a different character. Find the minimum number of operations required to satisfy the following condition: Any two adjacent characters in T are different.

Input is given from Standard Input in the following format:

```
S
K
```

Print the minimum number of operations required.

Below is the code that I've written.
I've separated the problem into 5 cases.

i) S is a single letter.

ii) S is two letters and they are the same.

iii) S is two letters and they are different.

iv) S is more than two letters and the first and last letters are different.

v) S is more than two letters and the first and last letters are the same.

```py
S = input()
K = int(input())
L = len(S)
sum = 0
x = 1

if L == 1: # i)
  print(K//2)
elif L == 2 and S[0] == S[1]: # ii)
  print(K)
elif L == 2: # iii)
  print(0)
elif S[0] != S[-1]: # iv)
  for i in range(0, L-1):
    if S[i] == S[i+1]:
      x += 1
    else:
      sum += (x // 2)*K
      x = 1
  sum += (x // 2)*K
  print(sum)
else: # v)
  for i in range(0, L-1):
    if S[i] == S[i+1]:
      x += 1
    else:
      sum += (x // 2)
      break
  y = x
  x = 1
  for i in range(y, L-1):
    if S[i] == S[i+1]:
      x += 1
    else:
      sum += (x // 2)*K
      x = 1
  sum += (x // 2)
  sum += ((x+y) // 2) * (K-1)
  print(sum)
```

My code fails 2 out of 15 test cases. I have no idea what part of my work is causing the issue. Can somebody point out which part of the code is problematic? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Can you explain which tests are succeeding and which are failing?

Comment: @JW. Unfortunately, AtCoder does not show users what each specific test case is. It just tells me that test cases 1 and 2 failed and the rest were ok.

Comment: Well...which are test cases 1 and 2?